# User in www-data group can't view directory

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I've added a user (`test`) to the group `www-data` with the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data test
```

When I try to view a directory with permissions `744`, it says `Server returned empty listing for directory` (lack of permission).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must give execute permissions on the directory for the group as well. The execute bit (on directories) allows / permits listings. so just do a

```
chmod g+x /path/to/your/dir
```